# Discord.js, JSDOM Invalid URL

Tags: discord.js, jsdom

So I'm trying to get the HTML of a website. I use 'JSDOM' to "Load" the website due to a majority of the site being created using scripts. My code is as follows:

```js
    (async () => {
        try {
            const dom = new JSDOM(``, {
                url: "https://www.google.com/",
                referrer: "",
                contentType: "text/html",
                includeNodeLocations: true,
                storageQuota: 10000000,
                runScripts: "dangerously",
                resources: "usable",
                pretendToBeVisual: true
            });

        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })();
```

When I run the command I get the error

```
TypeError: Invalid URL:
    at new URLImpl (C:\Users\jonco\Desktop\Nakada Manami\node_modules\whatwg-url\lib\URL-impl.js:21:13)
    at Object.setup (C:\Users\jonco\Desktop\Nakada Manami\node_modules\whatwg-url\lib\URL.js:73:14)
    at new URL (C:\Users\jonco\Desktop\Nakada Manami\node_modules\whatwg-url\lib\URL.js:105:22)
    at transformOptions (C:\Users\jonco\Desktop\Nakada Manami\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:239:43)
    at new JSDOM (C:\Users\jonco\Desktop\Nakada Manami\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:34:15)
    at C:\Users\jonco\Desktop\Nakada Manami\index.js:109:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

What am I doing wrong? I've spend the last 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The referer has to be undefined or a valid URL.
As we see that in the source.
[image]